# Traceback: list index out of range

Tags: python, list, random, grid

```
def PlayEasy():
    list = []
    filename = 'words.txt'
    with open(filename) as f:
        content = f.readlines()
    list.append(content)
    print(list)
    print(list[0] + list[1] + list[2])
    print(list[3] + list[4] + list[5])
    print(list[6] + list[7] + list[8])
```

Try to run but get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    PlayEasy()
  File "/home/bourne-grammar.lincs.sch.uk/99dj12/Documents/Ca2/2016-DJ-Traditional/CA2/Code.py", line 24, in PlayEasy
    print(list[1] + list[1] + list[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I'm trying to print out all 9 items of the list in a 3x3 grid.

Comment: I think you mean ``list.extend`` rather than ``list.append``.

Comment: also ... don't use `list` as a variable name, `list` is a built-in type that you are overwriting

Comment: Aos note that the error message doesn't match any code, you don't have a code line that says `print(list[1] + list[1] + list[2])`. Be specific! It will pay off in the long run.

Comment: Wrong error message from a previous test, however the problem was still the same but is sorted now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list has only one item - list of lines from readline.
You should use extend() instead of append().

A few more notes:

- I don't see why do you need `list` variable. Content is already a list.
- `list` is a keyword so it isn't a good name for variable.

Comment: Thanks, have removed list and just using content. Seems to be working now :)

Comment: Just waiting to, have to wait 2 minutes :')

Answer (score 0):

I think `content` is already a list. So you can `print(content)`.

Answer (score 0):

content is already list no need to append to new list.

But to avoid new line character declare a new_list like below

new_list = []

for line_data in content:
    new_list.append(line_data.strip())